# Result from split function is giving me a character each time instead of word

Tags: javascript, split, alert

```
var str = document.getElementById("kb").value.split('\\n');
console.log(str);
for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++){

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str[i];
    var token = str[i].split(/[\[\]]|,+/).join(' ');
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = token;
    for(var j=0; j<token.length; j++){
        alert(token[j]);
        console.log(token);
    }

}
```

In this case, I have got a textarea and each sentence is split if it encounters a '\n', '[',']' and ','.

When I run this, it displays an alert box displaying just one character at a time instead of a whole word.

My textarea is as follows;

[Toddler]

[¬Toddler,Child]
...

I would like to have token[0] to be Toddler, token[1] to be ¬Toddler and token[2] to be Child, etc.

Thank you

Comment: You mean you're getting a character in the inner loop, which iterates of the `token` string? That should be expected. Maybe you forgot about the `.join(" ")` you're doing?

Comment: can you post your textarea content as well

Comment: token is a string and alert had been given for each letter in token - alert(token[j]); & hence you are facing that issue

Comment: i thought that my doing token[j] that i'd be receiving Toddler as a whole and not as T o d d l e r all on separate alert boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `join` returns a string here:
`var token = lines[i].split(/[\[\]]|,+/).join(' ');`
Then you iterate over chars in this string.

Here is a fixed solution (also [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcLay7oe/1/)):

```js
var lines = document.getElementById("kb").value.split('\\n');
console.log(lines);
for(var i=0; i < lines.length;i++){

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lines[i];
    // var token = lines[i].split(/[\[\]]|,+/).join(' '); // `join` returns string!
    var tokens = lines[i].split(/[\[\]]|,+/).filter( (str) => str.trim() );
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = tokens;
    for(var j=0; j<tokens.length; j++){
        alert(tokens[j]);
        console.log(tokens);
    }

}
```

```html
<textarea id="kb">[Toddler] [¬Toddler,Child]</textarea>
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo3"></div>
```

[`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is used with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to remove whitespace tokens.